# IPAD xml parsing with attributes deal

Tags: ios, ipad, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing, xml-attribute

```
<category name="Local"> 
…
…
…
<category name="business"> 
…
…
…
<category name="politics"> 
…
…
…
```

This is my xml file, I'm not sure how to deal with attribute i am using NSXMLParser. My question is how to deal with above attributes in NSXMLParser. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The names are then in the attributes dictionary.

Edit:

If the following doesn't help you, you should read some introduction stuff.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([[attributeDict objectForKey: @"name"] isEqualToString: @"Local"]) {
        NSLog(@"found category with name Local");
    }
}
```

Comment: sir,i cant understand this?will u please explain this?