# Wrong value for url from xml

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, url

I parse a xml with this structure :

```
 <item>
        <title>Elena Lasida : « Une chance historique pour redéfinir la vie bonne »</title>
        <link>http://www.eglise.catholique.fr/actualites/389527-elena-lasida-chance-historique-dacceder-vie-bonne/?utm_source=rss&#038;utm_medium=rss&#038;utm_campaign=elena-lasida-chance-historique-dacceder-vie-bonne</link>
        <comments>http://www.eglise.catholique.fr/actualites/389527-elena-lasida-chance-historique-dacceder-vie-bonne/#comments</comments>
        <pubDate>Thu, 22 Jan 2015 14:41:36 +0000</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.eglise.catholique.fr/?p=389527</guid>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[« Changement climatique : un Kairos planétaire » est le titre de la déclaration du Conseil Famille et Société de la Conférence des évêques de France, en vue de la COP21, conférence internationale sur le climat (Paris, décembre 2015). Chargée de mission pour Justice et Paix, Elena Lasida commente cet appel. Propos recueillis par ClR. [&#8230;]]]>
        </description>
        <enclosure url="http://www.eglise.catholique.fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/01/conf_COP21_viénot_lasida_brunin_baujard-620x349.jpg" length="544809" type="image/jpeg"/>
    </item>
```

Here is my code :

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];

   else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {

        [currentPhoto appendString:string];
    }



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentPhoto forKey:@"url"];
    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
```

}

and the value of url which i obtained is :

url = "\n        \n            ";

If in xml i dont have an image , i obtain url="" ;

Comment: Try to delete the spaces in the xml file

Comment: if i do that : url=""

Comment: Your parsing data is looking like JSON so try to use NSJSONSerialization

Comment: I was trying and no results. I updated the xml format in my question . What was before was xml converted to json

Comment: Ok use this method  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict and using the attributes you can get the data of url

Comment: could you gave an example,please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774600/ipad-xml-parsing-with-attributes-deal

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues

Comment: attributeDict value is "version 2" and that's all :(

Comment: for the others tag everything it's ok , i can dipslayed the problem is only here with enclosure

Comment: if([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
{
    NSString *urlValue=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
}

Answer (score 0):

Data looking like JOSON data.
You can parse this like.

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [responseDict valueForKey:enclosure];
NSString *urlString = [dataDict valueForKey:_url];
NSLog(@"URL is: %@", urlString
```

);

Comment: I was trying and no results. I updated the xml format in my question . What was before was xml converted to json.